# Email Notification Using JavaMail

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail, email-notifications

I was trying a method to implement email notification Using JavaMail.I wrote the code and there is no error. But no email has been sent.
I am using GAE with JSF2.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
javax.mail.Session session1 = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

String msgBody = "This is a test mail";

try {
    System.out.println("Email notification is sending");
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session1);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myGmailId1@gmail.com", "Example.com Admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress("myGmailId2@gmail.com", "Mr. User"));
    msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
    msg.setText(msgBody);
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Email notification has been sent");
} catch (AddressException e) {
    // ...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your sender e-mail address either registered as the administrator of your app, or the e-mail address of the current user that's logged in to the app.

According to the [App Engine Mail API documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html#Sending_Mail):

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message **must be the
>   email address of an administrator for the application** or any valid
>   email receiving address for the app (see Receiving Mail). The **sender
>   can also be the Google Account email address of the current user who
>   is signed in**, if the user's account is a Gmail account or is on a
>   domain managed by Google Apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is going well!